# Send data React to Node

Tags: reactjs

good day!

Please tell there are misstake. When project run - **CountValue is {}**

i have fetch to send data from react:

```
let data = {pp: number};
    data = JSON.stringify(data);


    fetch('http://localhost:3001/number', {
        method: 'post',
        body:  data
    }).then(function(responce) {
        console.log('data submit success');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('got err', error);
    })
```

this is the server code

```
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var countValue = req.body;
  console.log('CountValue is', countValue);
});
```

How should I send data?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `headers` in your fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/number', {
    method: 'post',
    body:  data
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Comment: Thank, it's work! But when try in Google CORS, block access. "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response".

Comment: I have next cors in server:

Comment: res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");