# Send data react axios

Tags: reactjs

[Send data React to Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353649/send-data-react-to-node)

If send data with axios.

is it correct?

react:

```
let data = {pp: number};
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/number', {
        body:  data
    }). then((response) => {
        console.log('data submitted success');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('got err', error);
    });
```

this in server

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var countValue = req.body;
  console.log('CountValue is', countValue);
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're posting to a route called `/number`, and supporting a route called `/`, the root path. Is the router nested under `number` already? Those two have to be the same for your backend to receive the POST.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Is there any problem with the given code?

Comment: I tried to send data with fetch. With this code it works too.
And how to take response from server?

Comment: well i rave a responce. Added this in server res.end(JSON.stringify(countValue));
in front it return this:
[object Object]{config: Object {...}, data: 34, headers: Object {...}, request....
I need to "data: 34" assign in variable.
Does it mean that I should use (bodyParser.json()?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to put `bodyParser.json()` in your middleware.
For example:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

After that, you could use below code as your HTTP response in the controller.

```
res.status(200).json({ results: countValue });
```

I believe you don't need to use `JSON.stringify(countValue)`

Feel free to share more details for us :)